# How can convert this code from UWP to Windows App SDK?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3

```
public async Task<int> CreateNewViewAsync(Type viewModelType, object parameter = null)
        {
            int viewId = 0;

            var newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                viewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;

                var frame = new Frame();
                var args = new ShellArgs
                {
                    ViewModel = viewModelType,
                    Parameter = parameter
                };
                frame.Navigate(typeof(ShellView), args);

                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                Window.Current.Activate();
            });

            if (await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(viewId))
            {
                return viewId;
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Does the following answer work, and do you have any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> How can convert this code from UWP to Windows App SDK?

Above code does not work in Windows SDK, If you want to show multiple view in Windows App SDK, it's easy implement than uwp, you just make new Windows instance and then call [`Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.activate?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) method like the following.

```
private  void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = new MainWindow();
    window.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello World !" };
    window.Activate();         
}
```